# Appropriate ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I have this kind of data:

```
contract    nr   startdate
   1        12    01-01-2000
   1        12    03-01-2000
   1        22    07-01-2000
   2        77    12-04-2001
   2        78    17-04-2001
```

My simple goal here is to rank each number within a specific contract, taking into account the start date. The output should look like this:

```
contract    nr   startdate    my_rank
   1        12    01-01-2000   1
   1        12    03-01-2000   1
   1        22    07-01-2000   2

   2        77    12-04-2001   1
   2        78    17-04-2001   2
```

I have tried almost all possible combinations, but couldn't figure it out.

```
select dense_rank() over
    (partition by contract order by nr) as my_rank,* from my_data
```

The above is close enough, problem is that in some cases a 1 is assigned to the most recent contract, in other cases it is assigned to the least recent (?). 
Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ranking is by `nr`.

If you want to rank by the contract date, you need to incorporate that.  But these are different by contract.  So, that requires an additional calculation:

```
select dense_rank() over (partition by contract order by min_startdate) as my_rank,
        d.*
from (select d.*,
             min(startdate) over (partition by contract, nr) as min_startdate
      from my_data d
     ) d;
```

I don't know if you want the `min()` or `max()` of the start date for your ordering.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. It now looks like what I want.